# Is there any difference in position of the NSViews in the object menu in the interface builder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nib

Here is what I have in my Objects menu in the interface builder

[image]

Im curious if the order of ImageView , PaintView and PlayerView matters? In my case I want to stack them in the following order: PlayerView / ImageView / PaintView where paint view is on the very top (closest to the "user").

Does anyone know how I can do it here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  The hierarchy there will correspond to the drawing order of the views.  In your image, Paint View will be on top of Player View, etc.